# Normal convergence versus uniform convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am wondering about the nature of uniform and normal convergence. I know that uniform convergence is a weaker condition than normal convergence and that normal convergence even implies uniform convergence, but there is a situation that has me confused. My question is as follows:

If $f(z)$ is some complex valued function of the form
$$
f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)
$$
for some partial sums $f_n(z)$ so that $f(z)$ is uniformly convergent on any compact set $G \subset \mathbb{C}$, does it follow that $f(z)$ is normally convergent on $\mathbb{C}$? Or does a problem arise from the fact that we are convergent only on bounded subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, and so can say nothing about unbounded sets? Thank for any help in advance!

Comment: You can find the answer to a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679951/the-difference-between-pointwise-convergence-and-uniform-convergence-of-function or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597765/pointwise-vs-uniform-convergence

Comment: @Emin Neither of those questions mention normal convergence

Answer (score 1):

If we consider following simple example,

$$f_n(z)=-\frac{1}{n}$$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$.

Note that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly as its just convergent alternating series of numbers but it doesn’t converge normally.

Above example should also clear your thoughts about role of bounded-unbounded subsets.