# How to Visualize the uniform convergence of sequence and series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I've just started the "sequence and series of functions".I've read  the definitions of uniform convergence & pointwise convergence,but somewhere I am getting problem in getting the intuition.
It would be better if someone explain this using the graphs and authoritative statements.
Thamk you!!

Comment: As a start, these may help:
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/679951/159845
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/597765/159845

Comment: thanks for help,it made me clear.