# Evaluate this infinite sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(x^{3n-2} - x^{3n+1}\right)$

We can't simplify anything any more. Except.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{x^{3n}}{x^2} - \frac{x^{3n}x^3}{x^2} \right)$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n}(1 - x^3)}{x^2}$

Comment: Write out the terms of the sum in its original form and you will see how they cancel. You can write down the expression for the (finite) partial sums, and take the limit, if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand my comment a little, the sum begins $$(x-x^4)+(x^4-x^7)+(x^7-x^{10}) \dots$$

The sum of the first $n$ terms is clearly $x-x^{3n+1}$ (e.g. prove by induction).

Take the limit as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{3n-2} - x^{3n+1}=\dfrac{1-x^3}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x^3)^n$

If $|x^3|\le1,$ using [Infinite Geometric Series Formula Derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370662/infinite-geometric-series-formula-derivation),

$\displaystyle S=\frac{1-x^3}{x^2}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{1-x^3}=x$

Comment: Hi! Thanks. If $x^3 < 1$, then how does the sum converge to $\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}$?

Comment: Wait.. Did you use the ratio formula? the $S = 1/(1-r)$?

Comment: @Amad27, It's actually $$\frac a{1-r}$$ See link in the edited answer

Comment: @Amad27, Background : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002440/interchanging-summation-and-integral ?