# Turning sum to integral representation

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-sum

I'd like to turn this sum: 
\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)} \end{align}
into an integral $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \space dx$.

There seems to be many methods to either change or approximate sums as integrals. So I've become confused which approach would work.

In [Is it possible to write a sum as an integral to solve it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004081/is-it-possible-to-write-a-sum-as-an-integral-to-solve-it) robjohn used $\int_0^\infty e^{-nt}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac1n$ which looks similar to a Laplace Transforms.

I can't see how he gets rid of the n's so I'm not able to apply it here otherwise it seems promising.  But looking elsewhere there are also approximations methods such as: [Turning infinite sum into integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356472/turning-infinite-sum-into-integral) which even more obscure at least to me.

How do I convert this sum to an integral?

Comment: He got rid of the $n$'s by pulling the sum inside the integral. The sum with the exponentials was an easier problem than the original sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could write $$\frac{1}{n+1} = \int_0^1 t^n\; dt$$
so (for $|x| < 3$) your sum becomes
$$ 
\eqalign{\sum_{n=0}^\infty &\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^{n+1} \int_0^1 t^n\; dt\cr
= & \frac{x}{3} \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{xt}{3}\right)^n \; dt\cr
= &  \frac{x}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1-xt/3}\cr
= & \ln\left(\frac{3}{3-x}\right)\cr }$$

Answer (score 5):

Recall that
$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)} = \int_0^{x/3} t^n \ \mathrm{d}t$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{x/3} t^n \ \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{x/3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n \ \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{x/3} \frac{1}{1-t} \mathrm{d}t = -\ln \left( \frac{3-x}{3} \right)$$

This holds for $|x|<3$.

Answer (score 2):

If you differentiate it you will get a geometric series
$$\begin{align}
\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac d{dx}\frac 1{(n+1)}\left(\frac x3\right)^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac x3\right)^n\\
&=\frac 1{1-\frac x3}\\
&=\frac 3{3-x}\\
\text{Integrating:}
\qquad \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)}&=-\ln\left(\frac {3-x}3\right)=\ln\left(\frac 3{3-x}\right)\end{align}$$

__
* by Fubini/Tonelli's theorem