# Difference between convergence and uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know what is convergent series and a uniform convergent series from  defination . But please tell me what property a uniform convergence series acquire which is not aquired by a convergent series.ie which specialist is in uniform convergent. Please tell me.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointwise vs. Uniform Convergence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597765/pointwise-vs-uniform-convergence)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointwise vs. Uniform Convergence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597765/pointwise-vs-uniform-convergence)