# Equivalent definitions for pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

So for a sequence of functions $\{ f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ then
$f_n$ converges pointwise to some function $f$ if $$\forall x \in I, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0 :n\geq N \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon.$$
Is an equivalent condition for this:
$f_n\to f$ pointwise on $(a,b)$ if for each fixed $x\in(a,b)$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

and for uniform convergence,
$$\forall\epsilon > 0, \exists N>0 : n\geq N \implies |f_n(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon \quad \forall x \in I.$$
Is this equivalent to:
$f_n\to f$ uniformly on $(a,b)$ if $\sup_{a< x<b}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

I've searched around and every PDF file I see defines the definitions with the former for each.

Source:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/597777/424197

Comment: Look over your definitions. You have missed some parts.

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed it.

Comment: You are correct about the equivalent statements. One defines a norm $\|f\|_u := \sup f(x)$ and then has uniform convergence if $\|f_n - f\|_u \to 0$. Often this norm is instead denoted $\|f\|_\infty$ and functions that are equal on a set of measure (think: length, area, volume) zero are considered being the same function.

Comment: Thanks. I think I kind of get that (though, probably not fully because I haven't really learnt anything about measure theory and I've only encountered norms in the context of inner products). It seems like considering the supremum of a norm and showing that it doesn't approach 0 is much easier than finding specific values of $N$,$\epsilon$,$x$ when proving that a function does not converge uniformly?

Comment: Just to make sure: The second set of definitions are not iff statements right?

Comment: Where should "iff" be or not be, do you mean?

Comment: Sorry in the definition:  
$f_n\to f$ pointwise on $(a,b)$ if for each fixed $x\in(a,b)$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$  
instead of "if for each..." should it be "iff for each.."? (Most likely not since the equivalent definition isn't?)

Comment: The 'if' in a definition "X is said to be A *if* P(X)" should be thought of as 'iff'. If P(X) then we say that X is A, and if X is A that means that P(X). A definition is not a theorem, it's an introduction of a new notation or a new term as an abbreviation for a (usually) lengthy description.

Comment: For uniform convergence on an interval $I$, I prefer this sort of syntax:
 
$\forall\varepsilon > 0 \, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall x \in I \left(n\geq N \implies \left|\, f_n(x) -f(x) \right| < \varepsilon \right)$

Comment: Thanks guys. Last question: Is this "equivalent" definition of the uniform convergence ever untrue in any setting? (Maybe in some other topological space, I haven't really learnt much on topology, so just curious)