# On uniform convergence of functions with compact support

Tags: sequence-of-function

If sequence of functions $f_{n}$ in $C_C(\mathbb{R})$ converges pointwise to the functions $e^{-x^2}$, then can we conclude $f_n$ converge uniformly.

Comment: This may be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597765/353004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the sequence
$$
f_n(x) = (e^{-x^2}+\chi_{[n,n+1]}),
$$
where $\chi$ is the indicator function.

Notice that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, once $n>x$ then $f_n(x)=e^{-x^2}$, so $f_n$ converges pointwise.

On the other hand $\|f_n-e^{-x^2}\|_\infty = \|\chi_{[n,n+1]}\|_\infty = 1$ for all $n$.

**I now realize you want functions in $C_C(\mathbb{R})$, but hopefully you see how to modify this example slightly to that end**

Comment: Can you please explain how to modify???

Comment: @mathlover Rather than take $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$, take your favorite bump function in $C_c(\mathbb R)$ and add translates of it to obtain the $f_n$.

Comment: @Aweygan we can take $f_n(x)=e^{-x^2}\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$. Right? Then $||f_n-e^{-x^2}||_{\infty}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Then $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $e^{-x^2}$. Am I right?

Comment: @Aritra That's not continuous, and $\|f_n-e^{-x^2}\|_\infty=1$ for all $n$.  What are you aiming for?

Comment: @Aweygan I am trying to find a sequence of function $f_n\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $(f_n)$ convergers uniformly to $e^{-x^2}$.